# Как включить wsdl файл в package my.some.package при сборке jar в gradle?

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, soap

При компиляции jar'ок средствами Ant в них, по дефолтным настройкам, включаются и доп. файлы который нужны для проекта, т.е. в jar'ке, в пакете my.some.package будут находится не только .class файлы, но и wsdl\xsd. нужные для проекта. При переходе на сборку проекта gradle'ом выяснилось, что при сборке в итоговом jar файле, в пакете находятся только .class файлы, любые другие убираются.

Подскажите как нужно сконфигурировать build файл грэдла, чтобы при сборке файлы переносились? Копирование файлов в  Resources - не то, т.к. после сборки файлы лежат в корне архива. а не в нужном пакете.

Comment: может просто импортировать ant в gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась созданием таска в билд файле:

```
processResources {
 from 'data'
} 

task data(type: Copy) {
from 'пакет где лежат нужные файлы' into 'my.some.package'
}
```